# Yii2 - Adding html class to form file input

Tags: php, html, yii2

I'm trying to add a class to form file input in yii2, but it doesn't seem to work.

I'm trying to add `.cropit-image-input` to this form element.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'profile_picture_url')->fileInput() ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class property of element like following:

```
<?= $form
      ->field($model, 'profile_picture_url')
      ->fileInput(['class'=>'cropit-image-input']) 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add class to `fileInput()` like any normal input.

For Example,

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'profile_picture_url')->fileInput(['class' => 'cropit-image-input form-control']) ?>
```

[FileInput()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-basehtml.html#fileInput%28%29-detail)